Why I got "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" when trying to do `instanceof MongoBulkWriteError`?
Informations
I have such piece of code:
try {
  return await this.propertyTypesRepository.save(propertyTypeEntity); // this will fail 
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof MongoBulkWriteError) {
    console.log(error.name);
  }
}

And when the MongoBulkWriteError is imported as
import { MongoBulkWriteError } from 'mongodb';

(source file: node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts)
then eveything is allright.
Once I do an import of this class from different place
import { MongoBulkWriteError } from 'typeorm';

(source file: node_modules/typeorm/driver/mongodb/typings.d.ts)
then I got really strange TypeScript error message saying
TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Question
Why is this happening? Does anyone have an idea? I checked the definition of the two files - they are almost the same!

I've tried to use import from typeorm and mongo - only the declaration from mongo seems to be working.
